# How will the genetic mechanism of reproduction work in a species with four sexes, where there are two types of men and two types of women?

Tags: creature-design

I am writing a story about a certain population of people who were artificially settled on a terraformed planet. The main feature of this civilization is that they have four sexes:

Man-man
Man-woman
The male Wolf
Female wolf

At the same time, it is noteworthy that all women of this civilization always have only two children for one pregnancy (they never have only one child or three), who always have different genders and species – that is, they always have a human boy and a wolf girl or vice versa. How can the genetic mechanism of reproduction work in this civilization?

Comment: You're going to have problems with "having **always exactly** two children", as in practice even species that only have one child at a time are known to occasionally have twins: you could get 95%+, but not 100%. Also, miscarriages are common: the figure I know is 30-50% of all fertilized embryos for humans, albeit many of those happen too early to be detected without medical tools. Even if they always have exactly two embryos per ovulation (not impossible, admittedly), how do you avoid situations of identical twins (one embryo splits into two) or one miscarrying while the other remains?

Comment: When you say they have two children, do you mean lifetime or per--pregnancy? The two situations are very different, most of the comments seem to be assuming the latter.

Comment: @SoronelHaetir I was assuming per-pregnancy in my comment, as I'm not aware of any species where variation from the typical number of children in a pregnancy is nonexistent, especially not when the target figure is something other than 1. If the OP meant over a lifetime (which Tortliena seems to have assumed), then the question's premise falls flat from inability to ever grow the populace and thus an inevitable decline to zero.

Comment: (a) I've VTC'd a lot lately, so you're getting a break, but I should be voting to close as needs more focus. Asking us to explain the genetics of reproduction for an undefined species (I'll get to that in a moment) is way beyond violating the [help/dont-ask]'s book rule. (b) You don't have humans and wolves. You have a species that looks like a human and a species that looks like a wolf that have enough similarity in their DNA that they can cross-breed - and have done so long enough for the genetics have basically merged. *But you haven't explained any of that.* (\*Continued\*)

Comment: (c) What problem are you really trying to solve? On the surface, it appears you're asking us to give you a Masters degree level explanation ("genetic mechanism of reproduction") when what you might be asking for is "how do the birds and bees work here?" Can you explain the problem in more detail with simpler terms (meaning focus on the problem, not the terminology)?

Comment: you should probably state it is two per pregnancy in the question otherwise you are going to have a lot of comments about population sustainability.

Comment: How much of this inheritance mechanism is supposed to have evolved, and how much was added deliberately? Was the addition done by biological engineering, by gods, or what?

Comment: The question says that this species was created artificially: I am interested in how their genetic mechanism of reproduction will work if they have four sexes, where there are two types of men and two types of women?

Comment: The essence of the question is not that women always have two children during childbirth and at the same time necessarily of different genders (this is an important part of the question, but a secondary one), but to explain why we have two types of men and two types of women?

Comment: Is your setting based in fantasy, soft-science, or hard-science?

Comment: I need a solid scientific answer

Comment: @FrankThompson4 I disagree that you need a solid scientific answer. You need a good story. Start with what the story needs and let the reader suspend disbelief for the duration of the story.

Answer (score 1):

## sex not directly determined by genes

If you want to do sex determination via chromossomic makeup for your setting, you'll be in for a  hell lot of combinatory analysis.

Fortunately for you, not all species on Earth have their sex predetermined by their genes. The most well known example is sea turtles, for which sex is determind by the temperatures the fertilized egg has been exposed to after being laid in a hole on a beach. So you can use that as the basis for your own species and skip a lot of math.

There are also plenty of creatures with two wombs (kangaroos, sharks), so you can use that too.

Just say that females in your world have two wombs, in which multiple eggs are fertilized but then the first one to develop consumes the rest.

As for sex determination, it is environment based, done by certain hormones. Each womb secretes a different hormone so you get a male child in one and a female in the other.

Or do it like the turtles and base it on temperature. Have one womb more proximal to certain organs and the other more distal, so one womb is warmer than the other.

Comment: The essence of the question is not that women always have two children during childbirth and at the same time necessarily of different genders (this is an important part of the question, but a secondary one), but to explain why we have two types of men and two types of women?

Comment: @FrankThompson4 then you should open a new question asking that. As it is you asked for a how, not a why: *"How can the genetic mechanism of reproduction work in this civilization?"*

Comment: @FrankThompson4 The *why* seems to be answered by "this species was created artificially" (i.e. "for whatever reason the creators wanted"). The *how* is quite readily answered by saying that these "sexes" are not determined by chromosomes, but by some environmental or hormonal factor.

Answer (score 1):

As you put it in a comment

> but to explain why we have two types of men and two types of women?

And as you yourself have answered

> The question says that this species was created artificially: I am interested in how their genetic mechanism of reproduction will work if they have four sexes, where there are two types of men and two types of women?

Being an artificial species it would be pretty shameful if they couldn't even reproduce.

As for

> How will the genetic mechanism of reproduction work in a species with four sexes, where there are two types of men and two types of women?

Either hormonal imbalance, or environmental stimuli, but since they both are carried by the same woman, and gestate at the same time, the plausibility of having 2 uteri is high since lots of species on earth do, but always have just 2 children is extremely improbable.

Unless, they fight in the womb and only the strongest lives. Something along those lines.